# Insert New Line in SQL for Variable String

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to add a new line into a string within SQL that has an XML output. The string that is outputted is a variable that is the concatenation of 2 column values. I have tried adding char(13) + char(10) between the two values to make a new line but to no avail. Is it possible that this cannot be done because it is being read as one string and not 2 individual strings?

```
 @BilledName = B.BilledName + char(13) + char(10) + C.Company
```

the example above is a snippet of how I am trying to accomplish the task but will not return the expected value of BilledName on line 1 and Company on line 2.

```
 BilledName
 Company
```

I am receiving the following:

```
 BilledName  Company
```

Comment: What are you viewing the results in? If I run this in SSMS it shows on 2 lines --> `DECLARE @BilledName VARCHAR(100) = 'BilledName' + char(13) + char(10) + 'Company'; PRINT @BilledName;`

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure your variable **`@BilledName`** is of `text` or `ntext` type

It may be

> BilledName  Company

when you see the Query result. But when you paste it in **Excel** or **NotePad** it will be

```
BilledName
Company
```

Comment: Do not make sure the variable is `text` or `ntext`! Both are on the deprecation list and [will be removed from future versions of sql-server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). Use `VARCHAR(MAX)` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)` respectively.